# ¿como soluciono el problema de Ace.OleDB 12.0 en visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net

Tengo un problema al querer subir un archivo Excel a mi formulario en Visual Basic, ya que al querer hacerlo me aparece el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Busque por internet como solucionarlo e instale lo necesario para poder arreglarlo pero aun así sigo teniendo este problema.